# Swordfish Ceviche

Tags: ceviche

I messed up my ceviche. I totally forgot to use frozen fish ( I used swordfish). I did The whole process until I realized my mistake. Should I throw it in the garbage? Or washed and freeze it.. or what.. please help

Comment: Could you describe the process you used?  Ceviche doesn't require you to use frozen fish, though it probably affects how long you need to marinate the fish

Comment: What country are you in? My understanding is that in the US,  most fish you can buy in the store has been previously frozen to kill some microorganisms. (Fresh off the docks is a different story)

Comment: It would take a lot for me to throw out fresh swordfish.  I cannot imagine anything in the realm of normal food preparation that would make fresh fish inedible in the short term.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, you'll have made your decision by now, but for posterity:

[Swordfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swordfish) is a deep-sea fish.  As such, there are very few parasites that can cross over from its flesh to humans; pretty much the only ones are a few species of roundworm, the worst of which is [the Anisakis worm](http://www.fao.org/3/x5951e/x5951e01.htm).  Swordfish are less prone to roundworm infections than some other fish, but such infections [are not unknown](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4109596/).  Marinating in acid [kills some roundworm larvae](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/230338440_Survival_of_Anisakis_larvae_in_marinated_herring_fillets), but not 100%.

This means that whether or not you're willing to eat marinated swordfish that has never been frozen is really dependent on your personal risk assessment; we can't give medical advice here.  All I can say is that the risk of infection is very small, but not zero.